# Is it a good practice to use Runtime.getRuntime().gc() method in onDestroy() of an Activity?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

onDestroy() method of an Activity does not reduces my memory usage. I am allocating some memory onCreate() of an Activity, but onDestroy() of that same activity does not de-allocates the memory as seen in the Android Monitor.

So, I was using the Runtime.getRuntime().gc() method to clear the memory manually. I was calling it in onDestroy() method.

Is it a good practice ?

Comment: it's pointless. gc() is just a request, not an actual command. if you call it, and the JVM doesn't see any reason to run the garbage collector, it won't.

Comment: There is never any need to call `gc()` manually unless you're trying to fix an actual observable problem with the memory management behaviour of your code.

Comment: It's unnecessary to call System.gc();

Comment: When I am opening a new activity, the memory allocation takes place. If I go back and forth, the memory keeps stacking up. So, I was calling this method to clear the memory because this was leading to memory out of bound exception

Comment: If this is happening you have a leak in your Activities

Answer (score 2):

> I was using the Runtime.getRuntime().gc() method to clear the memory manually

That does not "clear the memory".

> When I am opening a new activity, the memory allocation takes place. If I go back and forth, the memory keeps stacking up

Then you have some form of memory leak. Use the [development tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html) to determine where the problem is coming from.

Comment: it is good to use `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` to reduce memory uses? I checked it in `Profile Inspector`. After destroying the fragment my memory uses reduces some MB.

Comment: @MDev: "it is good to use Runtime.getRuntime().gc() to reduce memory uses?" -- it is generally unnecessary. The runtime will run garbage collection when it needs to.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes, my memory uses reduced automatically without running `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`. I'm migrating my `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStateAdapter` to reduce memory uses. So, I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()` in reference to `FragmentManager` and the problem is that my RecyclerView onClick is not working on the 1st position of the item.